# How to use current_user_can() in register_rest_route()?

Tags: rest-api

I'm trying to assert `current_user_can()` in the `permission_callback` method of a `register_rest_route` function. However, it always returns false.

Upon further debugging, I see that `wp_get_current_user()` function returns ID zero, which probably means the `$current_user` global isn't available at the moment of execution.

That means [this example](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#permissions-callback) from the documentation shouldn't work:

```
<?php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/author/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
        'args' => array(
            'id' => array(
                'validate_callback' => 'is_numeric'
            ),
        ),
        'permission_callback' => function () {
            return current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' );
        }
    ) );
} );
```

And indeed it doesn't.

Further debugging:

```
<?php
// muplugins/test.php
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {

    // Works. Returns current WP_User.
    wp_get_current_user();

    // Works. Returns current WP_User.
    global $current_user;

    register_rest_route('test', 'user', [
       'methods' => 'GET',

        // In a closure. Does not work. Returns zero.
       'callback' => function() {
           var_dump(wp_get_current_user());exit;
       },

        // In a class. Does not work. Returns zero.
        'callback' => [new Something, 'test_wp_get_current_user_in_a_class'], 

        // In a function. Does not work. Returns zero.
        'callback' => 'test_wp_get_current_user',

        'permission_callback' => function() {
            // Does not work. Returns zero.
            wp_get_current_user();

            // Does not work. Returns zero.
            global $current_user;
            $current_user->ID;
        }
    ]);
});

function test_wp_get_current_user()
{
    var_dump(wp_get_current_user());exit;
}

class Something
{
    public function test_wp_get_current_user_in_a_class()
    {
        var_dump(wp_get_current_user());exit;
    }
}
```

How can I use `current_user_can()` inside `register_rest_route()`? Or yet, should I?

Comment: The answer right here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455745/wordpress-api-permission-callback-check-if-user-is-logged-in?rq=1

Comment: Or the docs on Authentication: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/ You need to send the nonce, or the user is not signed in.

Comment: This is correct. Do you mind posting an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the `wp_rest` nonce with the JavaScript request that you send to REST.

This nonce is what passes the information from PHP to JavaScript about which user is making the request.

Example:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="rest_auth_nonce" value="<?= esc_attr( wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ) ) ?>">
</form>

<script>
    jQuery.ajax({
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', jQuery('form').find('input[name="rest_auth_nonce"]').val());
        }
    });
</script>
```